# Can I omit site.pp to execute one class on all nodes

Tags: puppet

I habe puppetserver and three nodes. I created on master createuser.pp file with createuser class.
Additionally I created site.pp with following content:
node 'app01','app02,'app03'{
include createuser
}
Now executing from each app server: puppet agent -tv will create user. All work fine.
My question is can I do the same without defining site.pp manifest ?
I can of course add include createuser at the end of class definition in file createuser.pp
but how can i run it from all three app hosts ? Do I need to create a tag ?
Thanks for any tips.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> can I do the same without defining site.pp manifest ?

In any version of Puppet still supported, you can do it without a file named `site.pp`, but not without a "[site manifest](https://puppet.com/docs/puppet/latest/dirs_manifest.html)" in a more general sense.  This can be a single file of configurable name (default "site.pp"), or it can be the collective contents of all the files in a specified directory.  Either way, the site manifest is the entry point for catalog building.  Other manifests are consulted only as needed.

> I can of course
> add include createuser at the end of class definition in file
> createuser.pp

In current Puppet, top-scope code may appear only in the site manifest (though some historic versions were more lax).  Your class *should* be in a module, not in the site manifest, and in that case no, you couldn't use an `include` statement in the same file with the class definition.  You need a class declaration either in the site manifest or in some other class directly or indirectly declared by the site manifest.

> but how can i run it from all three app hosts ? Do I
> need to create a tag ?

On the agent side, tags are useful only for *limiting* which classes and resources are applied.  Only those already in its catalog are available -- you cannot use tags from that end to apply classes or resources that wouldn't ordinarily be applied.

You ensure that the class is in the node's catalog by declaring it in the site manifest (as you are doing now) or in another class directly or indirectly declared in the site manifest.

Comment: Thanks for fast reply. But still it is unclear for me. I ask differently. Is there a way to have instead createuser.pp and site.pp only first file with class definition and execution ? How in such case I need to run command on agent ?

Comment: @AndrzejKozlowski, If you are using a site manifest *directory* (which is the default in recent Puppet), then you can put a manifest such as you describe in that directory.  That will make it part of the site manifest, so that the top-scope declaration of class `createuser` is allowed.  **But you shouldn't**.  Class definitions belong in modules, and they should be separated from the code and data determining which classes are assigned to each node ("classification").